# Domain driven design - Entity is updateable in certain circumstances

Tags: java, object-oriented, domain-driven-design

Here is my business rule:

> Anyone (anonymous users) can make an Application (as in *to apply for something*). Applications can be updated until they are reviewed and approved by an officer. Approved applications cannot be updated.

Therefore I created an abstract class

```
abstract class Application {
    //various fields of application form
    //fields do not have setters, but they have getters

    public enum State {APPROVED, UNAPPROVED};

    public abstract State getState();
}
```

And since an Application can be in two states, I modeled them like:

```
public class ApprovedApplication extends Application{
    //an approved application can only be created from an unapproved application
    public ApprovedApplication(UnapprovedApplication ua) {
        //create it
    }

    public State getState() {
        State.APPROVED;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UnapprovedApplication extends Application{     
    //only unapproved applications can be updated
    public void update(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO) {
        //do the updating
    }

    public State getState() {
        State.UNAPPROVED;
    }       
}
```

Am I on the right track here or is this complete garbage? And what about Officer approving the application? Getting a bit lost here.

```
UnapprovedApplication.approve(Officer o);
```

or

```
Officer.approve(UnapprovedApplication ua); ?
```

Comment: consider a "copy-ish" constructor with the signiture `ApprovedApplication( UnapprovedApplication ua, Officer o )` - that is, to make an approved application you need the unapproved and the approver

Answer (score 5):

> Am I on the right track here or is this complete garbage?

Upon approval of an application, does the *nature* or the *content* of the application change?

If the nature of the application changes, (meaning, you can do vastly different things with it once it has been approved,) then you might be on the right track, though it will still be difficult to implement, because you will still need to create a new application object, (since it will now have to be of a different class,) copy the contents of the old (not-yet-approved) object to the new one, and update any references that already exist throughout your system, which were referring to the old object, to now refer to the new object.  That's an awful lot of work to do, so you better have some good reasons to do it.

If the nature of the application does not change upon approval, then modelling simply the state of an object by introducing a new subclass is, I am afraid, to use your own words, complete garbage.

Since you have already come up with an enum describing the state of the application, I would think that you should keep just one class and simply change its state from not-yet-approved to approved, and an approved application object will be preventing its content from being altered.  So, the `getState()` getter would be returning the value of some `private State state;` field.

> And what about Officer approving the application?

(Well, what about them?)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: How do I prevent approved apps from updating? Check and return without doing anything in update method? plus, added sth about officers :P

Comment: "does the nature or the content of the application change", things can be done with an approved or unapproved may vary. I thought it was a good idea that, if something requires an approved app to work, it should ask for an approved app, rather than silently validating the app in itself. Don't sure if mine is good design though

Comment: The caller should *never* attempt to update an approved app. Therefore, every setter should begin with `assert state != State.APPROVED;` or, better yet, `assert !isApproved;`

Comment: Of course, the things that you can do may vary.  The question is whether the difference is so radical as to justify considering the app as being of a different nature or simply being in a different state.  In my experience, situations like yours are indicative of a different state.  Usually, throughout its lifetime an object transitions through various states, it does not transition through various natures.

Comment: What do you mean by "nature"?

Comment: @RibaldEddie By "nature" I mean "type", but I did not want to directly use the word "type", because then the description of the answer would also be the explanation of the answer.  If you go to thesaurus.com and type "nature", you will find a tab for the "type, kind" meaning, containing such synonyms as structure, variety, anatomy, category, ilk, shape, species

Comment: @Reek as for the downvote, go figure, there is also a close vote. We have some *really* grumpy people in the midst of us!  Come on, cheer up people, merry Christmas, happy Saturnalia, whatever!

Comment: I generally disagree with the answer.  I've implemented a small set of states this way before and didn't have any problems with it. Not sure how this isn't an opinion question. If the states all share the same behavior then you put those methods in the base class. If they don't share the same behavior then you can define some interfaces for that and or use the template method pattern when it is suitable.  If you need to do things like transition from state to state according to business rules, you can do that too with methods like canTransitionToState() and getNextState() and so on.

Comment: If you've look up OOP implementations of state machines, I'm pretty sure you'll see the states modeled as classes.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding correctly, an unapproved application is the default state, which means either `Application` or `UnapprovedApplication` is redundant (remove one).

If you lock yourself into a corner by having business logic tied directly to your entity it's going to get ugly real quick.  Usually we do the business logic in a Service Layer that lives outside the entity.

In your service layer you would have the method `approve` which in turn would build your state object and set it on the entity.

Remember, an entity should closely match your persisted data (think getters and setters only)

How you transition between the states is subjective (business logic) and that should ideally always be done outside of your entity

Comment: You are saying to model the domain after the db design, a surefire way to royally screw thing up.  You also advocate an anemic model that's a useless property bag with the logic in another class.  Sounds like procedural design, not OO.  Just bad design all around.